# Weighted Pythagorean Triples

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Let $r,s,t$ be positive integers. Do there exist integers $a,b,c$, not all 0, satisfying $$r a^2+s b^2=t c^2\enspace ?$$

Let's call $(r,s,t)$ "valid" if such a solution exists, and "invalid" otherwise. The goal is to characterize the valid $(r,s,t)$ triples.

Note that we can always divide out by factors common to $(r,s,t)$, without affecting validity. We can also divide any of the terms by any square factor. Therefore, it suffices to characterize $r,s,t$ that are square free and share no common factors. If some prime factor $p$ divides two of $(r,s,t)$, we can first *multiply* by $p$, and then divide the two terms by $p^2$. Therefore, we can even assume that any prime factor divides at most one of $r$, $s$, or $t$.

Not all $(r,s,t)$ triples are valid: by looking at things mod 4, we can conclude that for valid triples, there must exist $A,B,C\in\{0,1\}$, not all 0, such that $r A+s B\equiv t C\bmod 4$. To see this, simply eliminate all common factors from $(a,b,c)$, and then set $(A,B,C)=(a^2,b^2,c^2)\bmod 4$. So for example, $(r,s,t)=(1,1,3)$ has no solution.

On the other hand, if $t=1$ and either of $r,s$ are equal to 1, then there exists a solution. Concretely, $(1,s,1)$ has a solution
$$(a,b,c)=\left(s-1\;,\;2\;,\;s+1\right)$$
An analogous solution shows that the triple $(r,1,1)$ is also valid.

Do any other valid $(r,s,t)$ triples exist? If not, how do we prove that the above captures all valid $(r,s,t)$ triples?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solutions to $ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification of Legendre's theorem re: $ ax^2+by^2=cz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987948/clarification-of-legendres-theorem-re-ax2by2-cz2). There are also multiple other questions about this, as you can find from the linked section of this question or by searching for "Legendre's theorem" on this site.

Answer (score 0):

eqn.: $ra^2+sb^2=tc^2$

Above has solution for, $(r,s,t)=(35,10,3)$

$a=5k^2-20k-4$

$b=10k^2+20k-32$

$c=25k^2-20k+60$

For, $k=1$ we have:

$35(19)^2+10(2)^2=3(65)^2$

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then by Bezout's identity $\exists (m,n) \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ma^2+nb^2=1$.

Then for any $tc^2$, we can set $r=mtc^2$ and $s=ntc^2$ to obtain $ra^2+sb^2=tc^2$.

In so doing, it may be the case that not all of $r,s,t$ are positive integers, but then all that is necessary is to rearrange the resulting equation and rename the variables $a,b,c$.

If we insist on dividing out common factors, we arrive back at $ma^2=nb^2+1^2$.

Answer (score -1):

The solvability of the diophantine equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$ can be decided by Legendre's theorem.
[Legendre's theorem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec24.pdf)

[ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2?noredirect=1&lq=1)