# When do there exist rational solutions to the generalized Pell equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

There are many questions on this site asking about integer solutions to the generalized Pell equation $x^2 - dy^2 = n$ for $d$ and $n$ integers and $d$ squarefree. What is known about the existence of solutions when we allow rationals? Do we only have rational solutions when we have integer solutions or is the situation more complex?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555147/rational-solutions-of-pells-equation) is relevant but only concerns the usual Pell equation $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$.

Comment: The answer by Phillip Gibbs to the linked question does not depend on the right side being $1$.  It may not be as specific as you are looking for, it is a procedure.

Comment: It becomes integer $u^2 - d v^2 = n w^2 \; , \; \;$  where $\gcd(u,v,w) = 1,$  with $x= u/w$ and $y = v/w.$  Conditions for   $u^2 - d v^2 = n w^2 $   are the subject of Legendre's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987948/clarification-of-legendres-theorem-re-ax2by2-cz2   ALSO the complete collection of solution triples is determined by triples of binary quadratic forms. This is page 47, Theorem 4, in Mordell's Diophantine Equations. Meanwhile, I like the treatment of Legendre in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms.  I see, Mordell writes Theorem 3 on page 46 about Legendre ternary

Comment: The solution by Phillip Gibbs starts with the trivial solution (1,0) then generates more, but we don't have a trivial solution here @RossMillikan

Comment: @WillJagy thanks for the link/references. Is it known when (if at all) rational solutions imply the existence of integer solutions? I guess that was the gist of my question, but you've given me plenty of reading material to start on.

Comment: It is easy enough to decide whether a number $n$  is integrally represented by at least one binary quadratic form of discriminant $4d.$ However, as soon as there is more than one form per genus...famous example, we can express $p = x^2 + 27 y^2$  when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  with the extra condition that $2$  be a cube $\pmod p$  See Hudson and Williams for similar examples, and the book Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$  by Cox;  HW: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy (I thought by HW you meant you were assigning me homework!) Thanks again for the references, I have read parts of Cox but not Hudson and Williams and the linked example is interesting. However I think you misunderstand my question. I understand we can skirt the 'rational solution' in practice and just check if there is an integer solution. But if I tell you that I have rational solutions to $p = x^2 + ny^2$ for some $p, n$ can we say anything about the existence of integer solutions? My guess is no.

Comment: Rational $x^2 + n y^2 = p $  says, with some restrictions on the common denominator of $x,y,$   that the prime is represented integrally by some $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2,$  where $b^2 - 4ac = -4n.$  Earlier example:  every prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  is rationally represented by $x^2 + 27 y^2.$   However, they are all integrally represented by either $x^2 + 27 y^2$  or $4x^2 + 2 xy + 7 y^2,$  but not by both.   Recommend  you run a small program, find the primes up to 1000  that are integrally   represented by $x^2 + 27 y^2,$  similar list for $4 x^2 + 2xy + 7 y^2.$  No overlap!