# Weighted sum of squares

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Suppose $A,B,C$ are integers.  When does the equation
$$ Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2=0$$ have a nontrivial solution in integer $x,y,z$?

I don't need all solutions, or even one solution, I just want to know if a solution exists. Specifically, I want an algorithm that is practical for small $A,B,C$.

I believe Lagrange did something with this, but there are so many results with his name that I haven't been able to find it.  Thanks.

Comment: You may need to assume $x,y,z\neq0$, otherwise $x=y=z=0$ is always its solution.

Comment: Thanks, it's added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem (Lagrange):**
Let $a,b,c$ be squarefree (positive) pairwise coprime integers. Then $ax^2+by^2=cz^2$ has a nontrivial rational or integral root if and only if
$$
\left(\frac{bc}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{ac}{b}\right)=\left(\frac{-ab}{c}\right)=1,
$$
where this should mean that $bc$ is a quadratic residue modulo $a$, etc. (it is better to use the notation $bc\, \square \, a$, $ac\, \square \, b$ and $-ab\, \square \, c$).

For, say, the example $5x^2+7y^2=13z^2$ we have
$$      
\left(\frac{7\cdot 13}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{5\cdot 13}{7}\right)=\left(\frac{-5\cdot 7}{13}\right)=1
$$
so that there is a nontrivial integer solution. For further references, also on this site, see here:

[Clarification of Legendre's theorem re: $ ax^2+by^2=cz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987948/clarification-of-legendres-theorem-re-ax2by2-cz2)

Note that there are versions with the wrong sign, see Will's correction!

[Solutions to $ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks, but Will's answer on that page gives the example of $5x^2+41y^2-21z^2$ which satisfies those conditions but has no solutions. The problem is that the Jacobi symbol does not identify quadratic residues if the denominator is not prime.  It seems that [this link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Legendre_theorem) given by Will has the correct answer.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Yes, the "symbol" is not the Jacobi symbol in general, but should rather be written $bc \, \square \, a$ etc. But it is a convenient "notation" of what you have linked.

Comment: Ok, but the Jacobi symbol for non-prime denominator has a standard definition which is not this.  So it is best to avoid this notation. Also, it is still wrong. Consider $a=9,b=-1,c=1$. It has solutions such as $x=5,y=9,z=12$, but $bc$ is not a quadratic residue mod $a$. You need  $a,b,c$ to be square-free as well.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Alright, I have added it. Your initial question was to find the right result among the many results by Legendre. I suppose you now know which result of Lagrange is meant and you can fill in the necessary details (and the notation you prefer). So what about your second question - you wanted "an algorithm that is practical for small $a,b,c$"? Here I found  an article by [Cremona](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4099841), and a paper by Holzer, saying that one only needs to check a rather small range of integers by computer, to answer the existence question.