# Results about generalised Pythagorean triples

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I reduced a problem I am working on to the question of whether the equation $$x^2+y^2=6z^2$$ has a non-trivial integer solution.

Thus I am looking for any results about the solution space of equations of the form $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: [Fermat's sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) addresses this.

Comment: The only [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D6z%5E2+over+integers) to this is trivial.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/proof-of-legendres-theorem-on-the-ternary-quadratic-form